# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal – MongoDB Error

Tags: database, mongodb, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to run this MongoDB script:

```
db.test_collection.insert({ 
_id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c), 
title: ‘Mongo Db practice’, 
description: ‘this class is about MongoDB’ 
})
```

and keep getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal @(shell):1:42
```

I think it has to do with with the _id and the ObjectId(7df78ad8902c) because when I put ObjectId("stringliteral") the error message changes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

try like this

```
db.test_collection.insert({ 
    _id: ObjectId('7df78ad8902c'), 
    title: "Mongo Db practice", 
    description: "this class is about MongoDB" 
})
```

For best practices don't add _id like `7df78ad8902c` it's not a correct mongoId. You can have issue with it in future.

if you have any question feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks for the response, it give me this error now:  [js] Error: invalid object id: length :
@(shell):2:10

Comment: I just changed it to a ObjectId('507f191e810c19729de860ea') and it worked

Comment: In better way you don't need to add _id manual. Mongo will create it automatically

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue while following the MongoDB quick guide at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_quick_guide.htm. The example for the insert method is incorrect:

> db.mycol.insert({
> _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
> title: 'MongoDB Overview',
> description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',
> by: 'tutorials point',
> url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
> tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
> likes: 100
> })

There are two problems with the example. First, the ObjectId needs to be enclosed in quotes. Second, the example has an invalid object id. The id should be a 12-byte hexadecimal value. For more information on what a 12-byte hexidecimal value is, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ and [How is a MongoDB ObjectID 12 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279842/how-is-a-mongodb-objectid-12-bytes)